# Iterating, selecting and computing different indexes in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe, here just sample data:

`length force   d1  d2  d3  d4
1   5000    300 300 300 300
1.2 5000    300 300 300 300
1.4 5000    300 300 300 300
1.6 2000    500 300 100 300
1.8 2000    600 300 200 300
2   3500    500 300 300 300
2.2 3500    300 300 300 300
2.4 3500    100 300 300 300
2.5 1500    100 400 200 300
2.6 1500    200 300 200 300
3   6000    200 200 200 100`

I have four parameters – `d1, d2, d3 and d4`. I want iterate through them and find a difference between a row and (row-1).  This difference should occur at least in one row for  two parameters (it can't be more, can be less tho). I thought I would add a new column to the dataframe `d1_test, d2_test, d3_test, d4_test` as follows:

`df['d1_test'] = df['d1'].diff() != 0`

So I would get:

`length force   d1  d2  d3  d4  d1_test d2_test d3_test 4_test
1   5000    300 300 300 300 False   False   False   False
1.2 5000    300 300 300 300 False   False   False   False
1.4 5000    300 300 300 300 False   False   False   False
1.6 2000    500 300 100 300 True    False   True    False
1.8 2000    600 300 200 300 True    False   True    False
2   3500    500 300 300 300 True    False   True    False
2.2 3500    300 300 300 300 True    False   False   False
2.4 3500    100 300 300 300 True    False   False   False
2.5 1500    100 400 200 300 False   True    True    False
2.6 1500    200 300 200 300 True    True    False   False
3   6000    200 200 400 100 False   True    False   True`

Let's consider each of paramater `(d1, d2, d3, d4)` also represents a fix value: `d1_pos = 30, d2_pos = 40, d3_pos=60, d4_pos=90.`

Then it comes the part where I can't figure it out. I want to add a new column (with computation), for instance `df['result']` which looks up when two of d1-d4_test are true. I could do that with Boolean sum(), so when `sum==2` but I can't know which two parameter are True.

In `df['result']` I want something like this:

```
if d1_test AND d2_test = True:
          df['force'] / (d2_pos - d1_pos)
     elif d1_test AND d3_test = True:
          df['force'] / (d3_pos - d1_pos)
     elif d1_test AND d4_test = True:
          df['force'] / (d4_pos - d1_pos)
```

and analogously for all other combinations. I don't think this is the right approach as I end up with many combinations. It is also a lot of work if number of parameter changes, for example if I add `d5, d6, d7`.

Expected result:

`length force   d1  d2  d3  d4  d1_test d2_test d3_test 4_test  result
1   5000    300 300 300 300 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   NaN
1.2 5000    300 300 300 300 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   NaN
1.4 5000    300 300 300 300 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   NaN
1.6 2000    500 300 100 300 TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   66.66666667
1.8 2000    600 300 200 300 TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   66.66666667
2   3500    500 300 300 300 TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   116.7
2.2 3500    300 300 300 300 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   Nan
2.4 3500    100 300 300 300 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   NaN
2.5 1500    100 400 200 300 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   75
2.6 1500    200 300 200 300 TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   150
3   6000    200 200 400 100 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    120`

I also tried with `groupby()` and slicing the data, but can't really figure it out. I'm sure there's way better solution out there?
  I hope it is understandable.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that. I corrected it.

Comment: Is the maximum number of `True` values for a given row always 2?

Comment: Yes, the maximum number of True always is always 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a mistake during copying, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method could work for any number of column `di` as long as you look for rows with only 2 `True`, assuming you have a list of the `di_pos` somewhere

```
list_pos = [30, 40, 60, 90] # [d1_pos ,d2_pos ...

# Use `filter`, `diff` and `values` to get all the values of the columns di_test at once 
arr_bool = (df.filter(like='d').diff() !=0).values

#create a mask where the sum in each row is equal to 2
mask = arr_bool.sum(1) == 2

#get the values in the rows using the list list_pos  and the mask
arr_val = list_pos *arr_bool[mask]

#create the column result using 
df.loc[mask,'result'] = df.loc[mask,'force']/(arr_val[arr_val .nonzero()][1::2] -
                                              arr_val [arr_val .nonzero()][0::2])

print (df)
    length  force   d1   d2   d3   d4      result
0      1.0   5000  300  300  300  300         NaN
1      1.2   5000  300  300  300  300         NaN
2      1.4   5000  300  300  300  300         NaN
3      1.6   2000  500  300  100  300   66.666667
4      1.8   2000  600  300  200  300   66.666667
5      2.0   3500  500  300  300  300  116.666667
6      2.2   3500  300  300  300  300         NaN
7      2.4   3500  100  300  300  300         NaN
8      2.5   1500  100  400  200  300   75.000000
9      2.6   1500  200  300  200  300  150.000000
10     3.0   6000  200  200  200  100  120.000000
```

Comment: Great solution. Could you please explain what exactly `arr_val[arr_val .nonzero()][1::2]` does? I don't quite get it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ziga `nonzero()` gives the index where the value in `arr_val` are not equal to zero and `arr_val[arr_val .nonzero()]` gives all the value of `arr_val` not null as a flattened array. Because you know that each row had two values not null, using slicing`[0::2]`get every two values of the flattened array from the first element, so the `di_pos` of each row and `[1::2]`get every two values of the flattened array from the second element so the `dj_pos` with i<j of each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean mask and then use `apply()` to apply your custom calculation to the remaining non-zero columns:

```
values = {'d1': 30, 'd2': 40, 'd3': 60, 'd4': 90}

mask = df[['d1','d2','d3','d4']].diff().fillna(0).ne(0)

def calc(x):

    vals = df[mask].iloc[x.name].dropna().index.tolist()

    if len(vals)<2: return None

    return x['force']/abs(values[vals[0]]-values[vals[1]])

df['result'] = np.where(mask.sum(axis=1)==2, df.apply(calc, axis=1), np.nan)
```

Returns:

```
    length  force   d1   d2   d3   d4      result
0      1.0   5000  300  300  300  300         NaN
1      1.2   5000  300  300  300  300         NaN
2      1.4   5000  300  300  300  300         NaN
3      1.6   2000  500  300  100  300   66.666667
4      1.8   2000  600  300  200  300   66.666667
5      2.0   3500  500  300  300  300  116.666667
6      2.2   3500  300  300  300  300         NaN
7      2.4   3500  100  300  300  300         NaN
8      2.5   1500  100  400  200  300   75.000000
9      2.6   1500  200  300  200  300  150.000000
10     3.0   6000  200  200  200  100  120.000000
```